# Using Ajax.BeginForm with MVC 4 - adding to my model collection asynchronously isn't working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous, model

I am trying to make a small football site where the user can create a new team and then asynchronously in another div it shows all the teams the user has created. So basically a team is created then added to the list of teams. All of this is in the model.

Now, I would like to do this asynchronously because its a nice to have but it's not working in my code. I am either missing something or it's not possible with what I am doing.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult TeamManagement()
        {
            modelTeamSelect modelTeamSelect = new modelTeamSelect();
            return View(modelTeamSelect);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult TeamManagement(string btnSubmit, modelTeamSelect modelTeamSelect)
        {
            switch (btnSubmit)
            {
                case "Add Team":
                    // For now - add to collection but not use DAL
                    modelTeamSelect.teams.Add(modelTeamSelect.team);
                    //modelTeamSelect.team.TeamName = string.Empty;
                    break;
            }
            return View(modelTeamSelect);
        }
```

**View**

```
@model Website.Models.modelTeamSelect

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Football App";
}
@section featured {

}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",

    Url = "Home/TeamManagement",

    OnComplete = "teamAdded()"
}))
{

        <div id="divTeams" style="float:left">
        <h3>Create a new team:</h3>

                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.team.TeamName)
                 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.team.TeamName)
                 <input type="submit" value="Add Team" name="btnSubmit" />

        </div>

        <div id="divCreatedTeams" style="float:left">
         <h3>Your created teams:</h3>
        @if (Model.teams.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Model.teams.Count; i++)
            {
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.teams[i].TeamName)
            }
        }
        </div>

        <div id="divLeagues">

        </div>

}
```

**Model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Website.Models
{
    public class modelTeamSelect
    {
        public modelTeamSelect()
        {
            teams = new List<modelTeam>();
            team = new modelTeam();
        }

        public List<modelTeam> teams { get; set; }
        public modelTeam team { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have the right javascript references being used in the project as I recently fixed this.

[image]

[image]

Why isn't my UI changing to reflect new contents of list?

Answer (score 0):

I dont get the idea of passing the submit button string to the Action. But in order to pass a ViewModel to the Action I think you have to write your own model binder. If you want you can try getting the models seperately in the action and combining them in the Action

```
 public ActionResult TeamManagement(List<modelTeam> teams, modelTeam team)
```

and combine them in the action in the viewModel.

Just a sugestion If you want to retrieve them async with ajax what I do is return partial view (i think better in your case) or json